# Webview keeps crashing

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

The code below is what I am using to create a webview that allows meleromusic.com to be shown. I am trying to make the webview show the website, but allow external links to leave the app. For example, if someone would click on a link that would take the user to the Play Store to install the app, they would simply leave the webview to go to the Play Store, instead of the play store being viewed on the webview.

```
package com.melero.music;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.CookieManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.webkit.GeolocationPermissions;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.webkit.DownloadListener;
import android.app.DownloadManager.Request;
import android.app.DownloadManager;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.net.Uri;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Allow third party cookies for Android Lollipop
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
        cookieManager.setAcceptThirdPartyCookies(mWebView,true);
    }

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt(String origin, GeolocationPermissions.Callback callback) {
            // callback.invoke(String origin, boolean allow, boolean remember);
            callback.invoke(origin, true, false);
        }
    });



    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath);
    mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

            String url2="http://www.meleromusic.com/";
            // all links  with in ur site will be open inside the webview
            //links that start ur domain example(http://www.example.com/)
            if (url != null && url.startsWith(url2)){
                return false;
            }
            // all links that points outside the site will be open in a normal android browser
            else  {
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        }
    });


    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.meleromusic.com/");
    mWebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener()
    {
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimetype, long contentLength)
        {
            //for downloading directly through download manager
            Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType("audio/MP3");
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, ".mp3");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
        }
    });


}














@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && this.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        this.mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}



}
```

Comment: Please, post logCat crash.

Comment: what do you mean by crashing?

Comment: After opening the app, it loads the website but after a second or two it closes the app